# Probabilty of two stage events (man & women) ; (smokers & nonsmokers)

Tags: probability

A person is selected at random from a population that has the following characteristics:

```
65% of the people are men; the others are women

12% of the men are smokers

7% of the women are smokers
```

i) Find the chance that the selected person is a man or a non-smoker

P(man or a non-smoker)= P(man) + P(non-smoker) - P(man of non-smoker) inclusion

P(man)=0.65 Given

P(man-non-smoker)= 0.65*(1-0.12)=0.65*0.88=0.572

P(women)=0.35 given

P(women-nonsmoker)=0.35*(1-0.07)=0.35*0.93=0.3255

P(non-smoker)=(p(man non-smoker + women non-smoker)=0.572+0.3255=0.8975

p(man or non-smoker)=P(man + non-smoker)-P(man of non-smoker)=
(0.65+0.8975)-(0.572)=0.9755  is this method correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds good to me. Alternatively, you may also go this way:
\begin{align}
P(\mbox{man or non-smoker}) & = P(\mbox{man})+P(\mbox{woman and non-smoker}) \\
& = 0.65 + 0.35 \times 0.93 \\
& = 0.9755.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Lord Soth for alternative Answer